# cython defining .pyd for class

Tags: python, compilation, cython

one of my classes is like below:

```python
class UnitFloat(float):
    ''' UnitFloat(value, unit) '''
    __slots__    = ('unit',)

    ### Make UnitFloat Immutable
    def __new__(cls, value, unit):
        ''' Create new instance of UnitFloat(value, unit) '''
        instance         = float.__new__(cls, value)
        instance.unit    = unit
        return instance


    def __getnewargs__(self):
        ''' Return self as a plain tuple. Used by copy and pickle. '''
        return (self.value, self.unit)

    value = property(float)

    def getIn(self, unit, decimal=None):
        ...

    def __add__(self, other):
        o    = change_other_to_self_unit(other, self.unit)
        v    = self.value + o.value
        return UnitFloat(v, self.unit)
    ...
```

I also have defined some magic methods like `__add__`, `__mul__`, `__pow__` , ...

I know Cython compile the internal types very efficient. but they are limited to int,float,bool,... . It seems that one must create an extension and use it. but I don't know how to define such extension for my sample class.

**Question:** I want to make a definition file (*.pxd) so Cython compile it better than Pure-Python-Mode, and I can use it like builtin types(int, float, long,..). How can I do this?

Comment: Augmenting pxd files are [explained in the documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html#augmenting-pxd). If you are unfamiliar with Cython you should first get familiar with it by writing a simple class in a `pyx` first. Be aware that Cython has a different interpretation of `__new__` and it would simplify things if you didn't depend on it to set up the class.

Comment: It sounds like you want to define a Cython [extension type](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html). As was just mentioned, you will probably want to start by doing that in a pyx file first.

Comment: can you explain how? specially for magic methods... \__add__